# Problem with fetching data from database in one to many polymorphic relations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have one to many polymorphic relationship in Laravel and I am trying to fetch data using eloquent query. I have Favorite model with favorites table

```
id   user_id   favoritable_id   favoritable_type
1       17           1          App\Models\ProfileImage
2       10           1          App\Models\PostVideo   this is some other model
```

and profile_images table with

```
id   user_profile_id   title   path
1         17           etc      etc
```

I need to fetch all profile_images from profile_images table that correspond to data in favorites table. So id from profile_images to match favoritable_id, user_profile_id to matches user_id and favoritable_type to match App\Models\ProfileImage from favorites table. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

Controller

```
public function getProfileImages()
{
    $profileimage = ProfileImage::whereColumn('id', 'favoritable_id')->first();
    // I AM BASICALLY STUCK HERE WITH $profileimage !!!

    $favoriteProfileImages = $profileimage->favorites()->where([
            'user_id' => auth()->id(),
            'favoritable_id' => $profileimage->id,
            'favoritable_type' => ProfileImage::class
        ])->get();

    return $favoriteProfileImages;
}
```

Comment: Don't quite understand what you desire. Do you want to get all records of ProfileImage which have been favorited i.e have records in favorites table. Or you want fetch all records from favorites table which are associated with currently logged in user

Comment: @Donkarnash I want profile images which have an entry in the favorites table for the currently logged in user

Comment: What is the relationship between User and Favorite - if any?

Comment: @Donkarnash In Favorite model I have public function user(){return $this->belongsTo(User::class);} with user_id in favorites table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Assuming that there is no relation between User and Favorite models, get all the PostImage records which have an entry in favorites table for the currently logged in user.

```php
$profileImages = Favorite::where('user_id', auth()->id())
    ->with([
        'favoritable' => fn($query) => $query->where('favoritable_type', ProfileImage::class)
    ])
    ->get()
    ->pluck('favoritable')
    ->flatten()
    ->all();
```

**Option 2**

Assuming that User hasMany Favorite records - hasMany relationship exists

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function favorites()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
    }

    // ...rest of the class code
}
```

Get the results via the User model

```php
$profileImages = User::with([
    'favorites' => 
        fn($query) => $query->where('favoritable_type', ProfileImage::class)->with('favoritable')
    ])
    ->where('id', auth()->id())
    ->first()
    ->favorites
    ->pluck('favoritable')
    ->flatten()
    ->all();
```